# Yanking results displayed in status line

Tags: key-bindings, cut-copy-paste

After pressing `<C-g>` in normal mode, prints useful information in the status line. How can I yank this text?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: If you use tmux you can yank any text printed to the terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of `<C-g>` is the same as that of the [`:file`](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#CTRL-G) command with no arguments.

In order to capture the contents of a command such as `:file`, you can use the [`execute()`](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#execute%28%29) Vimscript function.

For example, to paste those contents below the current line, in the current buffer, you can use:

```
:put =execute('file')
```

Or to capture those contents in register `x`, you can use:

```
:let @x = execute('file')
```

Followed by something like `"xp` to paste those contents from the register into the buffer.

Comment: And of course with clipboard support `:let @* = execute('file')`